# Reflection and group variables

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am not sure yet what is the best way to do this, I found that you can assign attributes to a class but there is no way to assign an attribute to a variable of the class.

Example

```cs
[attribute author....]
public class ABC
    int variable1;
```

what I am looking for is to assign an attribute to `variable1`.

so something like this

```cs
[attribute author....]
public class ABC
    [attribute or something to tie to variable1]
    int variable1;
```

So when I use reflection to access the class, I can get additional information from each variable. The reason for this is that I am creating an editor and I want to group variables in the editor but I don't want to hard code the variable names or keep a list of variables that should be grouped.

Any idea how to make something like that?

Comment: When you say a variable do you actually mean a member variable within the class?

Comment: In other words, a *field*.

Comment: yes ,  a field , member class, or also a property, anything that a user can set should have an additional property/attribute or something so my editor can pick up those extra details for presentation

Comment: _"there is no way to assign an attribute to a variable of the class"_ -- untrue. See marked duplicates.

Comment: Thank you Peter Duniho, that resolved my question. Just tested and worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

class_name.GetType().GetFields() returns the class variables aka fields.
Use a Dictionary to store attributes for these fields.

Comment: I am already doing that, but I want to group my fields for presentation , for example there are fields from one class  
        [DataMember] public bool drawTop    { get; set; } = true;  
        [DataMember] public bool drawBottom { get; set; } = true;  
        [DataMember] public bool drawLeft   { get; set; } = true;  
        [DataMember] public bool drawRight  { get; set; } = true;  
when i get them from reflection i do not know if i can group them in the editor or display them in different lines